# Best Status Code for Default Data (pre-requisites) Not Found

Tags: database, api, rest

Generally we have some default data in the database while deploying applications. This may be seeded when database is installed.

Now I just create one exceptional case. I deployed and configured database but not added the default data.

In this case when API is called, which status is best suited for me?

May be 200 with some custom status or 428 or like that. Please suggest the best option

Answer (score 0):

Since the client request is semantically valid and the client therefore is not at fault, I would not return any code in the 400-range.

It seems the server is at fault - so a code in the 500-range seems appropriate.

Perhaps **HTTP 501 Not implemented** is appropriate, since (from Wikipedia) "The server either does not recognize the request method, or it lacks the ability to fulfill the request. Usually this implies future availability (e.g., a new feature of a web-service API)."

The point regarding 'future availability' might make this the correct code.

Comment: nice i also support this